# WHERE clause in liquibase changelog to create database

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, liquibase, changelog

How can I generate this SQL statement in my changelog file with liquibase?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RL_UK on RUN_LOG(status) WHERE status = 'R'
```

I have tried it like this but it doesnt work:

```
    <changeSet author="Ferid (generated)" id="1528876614155-232">
    <createIndex indexName="RL_UK" tableName="RUN_LOG" unique="true">
        <where> status='R'</where>
    </createIndex>
```

I dont use this changelog file to update the database but to create it.

Comment: You need to use a `<sql>` tag

Comment: where do I need to use a <sql> tag?

Comment: Inside your changeSet. Instead of the `<createIndex>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clause is not available.

As suggested in comments, you could write custom SQL statments with  tag but you will have to take care of the rollback yourself :

```
<changeSet author="Ferid (generated)" id="1528876614155-232">
    <sql>
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RL_UK on RUN_LOG(status) WHERE status = 'R';
    </sql>
    <rollback>
        <sql>
            DROP INDEX RL_UK on RUN_LOG;
        </sql>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Although I would personnally suggest that you use the  tag properly without the WHERE CLAUSE because :

- I can't understand what you are trying to achieve with this where clause. Espacially since it is on the same column
- Your changeset probably won't be compatible with all databases supported by Liquibase so it will work with Postgres and fail with Oracle for example. The WHERE CLAUSE in the CREATE INDEX statement is probably not even ANSI-SQL
- You add bothering about the rollback for a very simple statement => not worth. Auto-rollback is available on every supported databases for this tag. Check it here : http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_index.html